# Image gallery in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery, image-gallery

Is it possible to create an image gallery in wordpress that is managed by the admin via it's own page / panel.  I am not talking about creating a new post and adding custom html for each image.  I mean actually having a page in the admin that has the ability to upload and manage your images?

If it is possible how do you go about creating a custom page like this?  I understand the PHP side of uploading and manipulating images, but I don't know how to integrate it with wordpress.  I don't need a full blow tutorial on how to do this, but if you could just point me in the right direction that would be great.

One issue that comes to mind right away, is if this is possible would upgrading wordpress break the code?  Since I assume you have to edit the admin files directly and you can't just do it from your own custom template?

Answer (score 2):

From playing around I found NextGEN Gallery (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) that has a tab in your admin panel. It looks like it would meet your needs.

Comment: If NextGEN doesn't meet your needs, a nice "top 10" list can be found here:
http://techpp.com/2009/06/18/top-10-wordpress-gallery-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

You can manage all your media from the WordPress Media Library using tags if you install [Tag Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-gallery/)

It requires the Media Tags plugin but it makes managing galleries so much easier and your using the built in media facilities of WordPress so it's not disjoint from the experience. There is a new version in the works that will offer much more impressive functionality as well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge amount of image galleries for wordpress already made. Have a quick google for some (search "wordpress image gallery") and see if any of them are suitable (I'll be surprised if one of them isn't).

Failing that, you'll need to create yourself a [Wordpress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/).

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated [ZenPhoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/) into my wordpress blog. It was pretty easy, would probably take you a few hours. The admin pages are completely separate from the wordpress admin pages, so you can easily give access to only one person.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type called Gallery to manage create and manage image galleries.  The post will have its own "Gallery" panel in the admin section and from there you can add new galleries just as you describe.  There are lost of tutorials for creating gallery custom post types.